# SQL server connectivity using ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString

Tags: asp.net, database-connection

I am not able to use

```
String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DevBackup"].ConnectionString;
```

I am getting error 'The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context'
I have used namespaces

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
```

what should be done..?? Am I missing something..??

Answer (score 5):

You need to add a reference to the `System.Configuration` assembly to your project, and then a `using System.Configuration;` statement to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have `System.Configuration` in your namespaces?

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET, `System.Web.Configuration` is the correct namespace to use:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DevBackup"].ConnectionString;
```